# How to use ngRedux in popup window?

Tags: angular, redux

In my application I am opening a popup like in:

```
window.open('myURL',"popup","menubar=1,...");
```

But then I am trying to get information from one of my stores like in:

```
constructor(private ngRedux:NgRedux<IAppState>){
   this.ngRedux.subscribe(()={
        this.myStoreValue=ngRedux.getState().myStore.myStoreValue;
   }
};
```

It seems like ngRedux subscribe is not triggering so I am not able to get the values from the store. Any idea why?
Also this store works properly in any other component in the application, as long as it is not a popup.

Comment: is the target URL of the popup also a angular app?
Every browser window/tag run it's own instance. It is not the same app inside the popup.

Comment: yes, the URL is route in my routing module, like in: { path:'myURL', component:myComponentForMyURL }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not possible without localstorage or cookies.
The redux store is not permanent. On reload all information is lost. In your case it's like a reload (new instance of the app).

Sorry, for bad news. :-/

Maybe something like [ngrx-store-localstorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrx-store-localstorage) is a possible solution for you.